# Specific format of datetime in insert to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have problem. I have script with more insert where is datetime in format 'DD.MM.YYYY'.

Problem is that server understand it as 'MM.DD.YYYY', so half of dates import with wrong value and half of dates do error.

Is any simple way how to say server that what is correct format?

I know that in past, if I worked with Oracle, I solve it by to_date function where I could specify format.

Comment: Can you change your insert to yyyy-mm-dd format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using something like this should work:

```
convert(datetime, '28.6.2011', 104)
```

From here:
http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 3):

I believe http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907 holds the answer

eg

```
set dateformat dmy
```